# Extract SCORM Quiz Data

Tags: php, xml, scorm1.2

I'm creating a system that needs to be able import SCORM-compliant (SCORM 1.2) videos.  However, I'm using Articulate, and when publishing, it is only providing an XML file for the actual presentation data, not the quiz.  (Quiz data is locked up in .swf files.)

Is the quiz part of SCORM-compliance?  If so, how do I extract the quiz data (questions, answers, etc.) into XML/CSV format?  I'm using PHP.

Thanks!

Edit:
I'm looking to store the Quiz data in a database and need the data out of the SCORM container.    I want to be able to import this data into the system, then discard the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SCORM, the definition of the quiz isn't published as a static definition. As the learner progresses through the content, the SCO will report interaction details at run-time. You will need to mine the quiz data from these reported interactions.

You can get a list of all the interaction data model elements in this [SCORM run-time reference chart](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/).

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was under the impressions SCORM was a standardized format for moving course data...  But it's actually a container for course data?  So... I'm stuck using the Flash?